# Program not compiling due to error in the value returning function. It says undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, function, return, boolean

I'm coding a program for rock paper scissors where there is a user player and a computer player. I believe everything is fine up to the bool value returning function. It needs to take two arguments (computer's choice, player's choice) and see if they are equal to print out "Tie". However, I'm getting an error that says undeclared identifiers for my two arguments.

I tried changing it to an int function instead of bool. and have my bool statements in main, but it did not work

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iomanip>
  #include <string>
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <ctime>
  #include <cmath>

 using namespace std;

int getComputerChoice();
int getPlayerChoice();
bool isTie (int, int);

 int main()
  {

char choice;
int compChoice;
int plaChoice;


do
{
    cout << "ROCK PAPER SCISSORS MENU" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "p)Play Game" << endl;
    cout << "q)Quit" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your choice : " << endl;
    cin >> choice;


    while (choice != 'p' && choice != 'q')//or if//why &&
    {
        cout << "Invalid selection. Try again." << endl << endl << endl;
        cin >> choice;
    }

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 'p':
        compChoice = getComputerChoice();

        plaChoice = getPlayerChoice();

        if (plaChoice == 1)
        {
            cout << "You chose: Rock" << endl;
        }
        else if (plaChoice == 2)
        {
            cout << "You chose: Paper" << endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "You chose: Scissors" << endl;
        }


        if (compChoice == 1)
        {
            cout << "The computer chose: Rock" << endl;
        }
        else if (compChoice == 2)
        {
            cout << "The computer chose: Paper" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The computer chose: Scissors" << endl;
        }


        if (isTie(compChoice, plaChoice))
        {
            cout << "It is a Tie!";
        }



        break;


    case 'q':
        cout << "You have chosen to quit the program. Thank you for using the program!" << endl;
        break;

    }

} while (choice != 'q');


 return 0;
}



  int getComputerChoice()
   {
int comp = 0;
int rando = 0;
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

rando = rand() % 3 + 1;

switch (rando)
{
case 1:
     comp = 1;
    break;

case 2:
    comp = 2;
    break;

case 3:
    comp= 3;
    break;

    return comp;
}
  }


   int getPlayerChoice()
  {

int player;
cout << "Rock, Paper or Scissors?" << endl;
cout << "1) Rock" << endl;
cout << "2) Paper" << endl;
cout << "3) Scissors" << endl;
cout << "Please enter your choice: " << endl;
cin >> player;

while (player != 1 && player != 2 && player != 3)
{
    cout << "Invalid" << endl;
    cin >> player;
}
return player;
    }

  bool isTie(compu, playa)
   {
if (compu == playa)
    return true;
else
    return false;

     }
```

These are the error messages I'm getting
compu': undeclared identifier
playa': undeclared identifier
'isTie': redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
see declaration of 'isTie'
'isTie': function-style initializer appears to be a function definition

Comment: Unrelated: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once). Putting `srand` in a function immediately before generating a number means multiple calls to the function will be broken and barely random if at all. That said, [`rand` sucks in general.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: At function `isTie` implementation, declare it with a valid prototype : `bool isTie(int compu, int playa)` and NOT `bool isTie(compu, playa)`. Just add the `int` (type specifier). You are close: then it works !

Answer (score 1):

`isTie` is a function that has 2 parameters.
From your code, I can see that it's expecting 2 `integers`.

So you need to update the function signature to:

```
bool isTie(int compu, int playa)
```

Comment: Same conclusion at the same time Comrad !